# Clear project date field via PSI

Tags: project, psi

How can i clear date format field in project using PSI?
i do

```
taskRow.TASK_FINISH_DATE = newTask.FinishDate;
```

Where taskRow is ProjectDataSet.TaskRow class and newTask.FinishDate is DateTime  But there are GeneralDateNotValid exception - TASK_FINISH_DATE cant be less than 01.01.1984.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is method

```
taskRow.SetTASK_FINISHDATENull();
```

it works.